# Dealing with attribute conditions in XML and Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I'm trying to modify an XML using Python.

Basically what I would like to do is look at the "condition" attribute of elements and based on that remove/keep elements in my XML. I would also need my code to understand when the attribute has a "not" or "or" condition in it (not sure if this is possible using python and lxml).

In my example XML below I would like to query that if the attribute condition = 1, it would remove all other elements except that element which contains condition="1". And it should only remove those elements that actually have a condition attribute, so the title element should stay, because it does not have the condition attribute at all.

Original XML:

```
<book>

    <chapter id="hi" condition="2">Item 3</chapter>

    <chapter id="hi" condition="1 or 2">Item 3</chapter>

    <chapter id="hi" condition="1">Item 2</chapter>

    <title title="Test">Item 1</title>

</book>
```

So if "condition" = 1 ->

Output XML (should look like this):

```
<book>

    <chapter id="hi" condition="1 or 2">Item 3</chapter>

    <chapter id="hi" condition="1">Item 2</chapter>

    <title title="Test">Item 1</title>

</book>
```

I've tried using different queries xpath/lxml etc, just can't understand how to solve this, is it even possible to do using Python?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please share the approach that you have used or if any code that you have tried.

Comment: I've tried using xpath query "".//*[not (@condition='1')]", but this just removes everything else than the element which contains 1..

Comment: @Splinter Can we assume that only 'chapter' elements comes with a 'condition' attribute?

Comment: @balderman This for just for sake of an example, so no, in theory, any element can come with the 'condition' attribute, not just chapter

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4).

Use `BeautifulSoup()` to create a `BeautifulSoup` object from a string version of the input XML.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(x, "xml")
```

The second argument of `BeautifulSoup()` specifies the parser. See [this](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser).

Now let us create a variable `n` which has the value to be found which in the example you have given is `1`.

```
n = 1
```

Use [`find_all()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) to iterate over all the tags present in `soup`.

```
for t in soup.find_all():
    ....
```

Now use  `has_attr()` to see if the tag has an attribute named `'condition'`.

```
if t.has_attr('condition'):
    ....
```

If such an attribute exists, we can get its value using `t['condition']`. Split the thus obtained string to get the integers out of it (assuming it is an integer that you want) to get a list of operands. `if x.isdigit()` is used to get rid of `and`, `or`, etc.

```
operand_list = [int(x) for x in t['condition'].split() if x.isdigit()]
```

If `n` is not in the operand_list, remove the tag from the XML tree using [`decompose()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose).

```
if n not in operand_list:
    t.decompose()
```

After the loop is over, let's print the resultant XML formatted using the [`prettify()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#pretty-printing) function:

```
print(soup.prettify())
```

Piecing together all the parts, the final program would be

```
n = 1
for t in soup.find_all():
    if t.has_attr('condition'):
        operand_list = [int(x) for x in t['condition'].split() if x.isdigit()]
        if n not in operand_list:
            t.decompose()
print(soup.prettify())
```

The output would be

```
<book>
 <chapter condition="1 or 2" id="hi">
  Item 3
 </chapter>
 <chapter condition="1" id="hi">
  Item 2
 </chapter>
 <title title="Test">
  Item 1
 </title>
</book>
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for! What about if I want to have several "n" values, like a list for example? n = [1, 2, 3], how would I go about looping through this list of values and removing all other than these?